# what's the relationship between gridgain and Apache ignite? Are they same?

Tags: gridgain, ignite

I am puzzled with the relationship between gridgain and ignite.I couldn't find out the difference.They both belong to Apache?Are they same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridGain adds enterprise features to Ignite. All Ignite APIs remain unchanged and are available in GridGain.

Here is the comparison:
http://www.gridgain.com/products/software